# Match only spefic url via regex

Tags: regex

I want to match only this specific url

```
https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3/about?lst=100002159119314%3A100022260619396%3A1507039852
```

Here's the source code

```
<div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_17"><!-- <div class="fbTimelineTopSectionBase _6-d _529n"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_above_header_timeline" data-referrer="pagelet_above_header_timeline"></div><div id="above_header_timeline_placeholder"></div><div class="fbTimelineSection fbTimelineTopSection"><div id="fbProfileCover"><div class="cover" id="u_0_13"><a class="coverWrap coverImage" data-referrerid="100022260619396" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=118243868927633&amp;set=a.117907638961256.1073741827.100022260619396&amp;type=3" rel="theater" ajaxify="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=118243868927633&amp;set=a.117907638961256.1073741827.100022260619396&amp;type=3&amp;size=1440%2C1080&amp;source=10&amp;player_origin=profile&amp;referrer_profile_id=100022260619396" data-ploi="https://scontent.fmnl4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/22136852_118243868927633_2950847275004458372_o.jpg?oh=fbcb3c8abc2023b35a5a36fb2989d850&amp;oe=5A821DA8" title="Cover Photo" id="u_0_12" data-cropped="1"><img class="coverPhotoImg photo img" src="https://scontent.fmnl4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/c0.81.851.315/p851x315/22136852_118243868927633_2950847275004458372_o.jpg?oh=7d0222f3c38b31acb33a7b1ffba2ac9e&amp;oe=5A797385" style="top:0px;width:100%" data-fbid="118243868927633" alt="Cover Photo, Image may contain: 1 person, sitting" /><div class="coverBorder"></div><img class="coverChangeThrobber img" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yk/r/LOOn0JtHNzb.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></a><div class="_2nlj _2xc6"><h1 class="_2nlv"><a class="_2nlw" href="https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3"><span id="fb-timeline-cover-name" data-testid="profile_name_in_profile_page">Princess Austine Alcantara</span></a><span class="_2nly"></span></h1></div></div><div id="fbTimelineHeadline" class="clearfix"><div class="_50zj"><div class="actions _70j"><div class="_5h60 actionsDropdown" id="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions" data-referrer="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions"></div></div></div><div class="_70k"><ul class="_6_7 clearfix" data-referrer="timeline_light_nav_top" id="u_0_14"><li><a class="_6-6 _6-7" href="https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3?lst=100002159119314%3A100022260619396%3A1507039852" data-tab-key="timeline">Timeline<span class="_513x"></span></a></li><li><a class="_6-6" href="https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3/about?lst=100002159119314%3A100022260619396%3A1507039852" data-tab-key="about">About<span class="_513x"></span></a></li><li><a class="_6-6" href="https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3/friends?lst=100002159119314%3A100022260619396%3A1507039852&amp;source_ref=pb_friends_tl" data-tab-key="friends">Friends<span class="_gs6"><span id="u_0_10">7 Mutual</span></span><span class="_513x"></span></a></li><li><a class="_6-6" href="https://www.facebook.com/princessaustine.alcantara.3/photos?lst=100002159119314%3A100022260619396%3A1507039852&amp;source_ref=pb_friends_tl" data-tab-key="photos">Photos<span class="_513x"></span></a></li><li><div class="_6a uiPopover _6-6 _9rx" id="u_0_15"><a class="_9ry _p" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" rel="toggle" role="button" id="u_0_16">More<i class="_bxy img sp_AWfL8SqGWNa sx_41c408"></i></a></div></li></ul></div><div class="name"><div class="photoContainer"><div><a class="profilePicThumb" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=116140922471261&amp;set=a.116141002471253.1073741826.100022260619396&amp;type=3&amp;source=11&amp;referrer_profile_id=100022260619396" rel="theater" id="u_0_11"><img class="profilePic img" alt="Princess Austine Alcantara&#039;s Profile Photo, Image may contain: 1 person, smiling, closeup" src="https://scontent.fmnl4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c0.0.160.160/p160x160/22050231_116140922471261_8103110572544919612_n.jpg?oh=d942ae339c7c9dc7c8add2e3dd34f6c4&amp;oe=5A413CB6" /></a></div><meta content="https://scontent.fmnl4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/22050231_116140922471261_8103110572544919612_n.jpg?oh=e43d8f6e5cfb1387f1a5d864b7947225&amp;oe=5A3CC115" itemprop="image" /></div></div></div></div></div>
```

I tried to use this regex code below but it also match other items inside. How can i match only that specific url? Thanks

The class is dynamic.

```
(?i)(?<=a class=".+" href=").*?(?=" data-tab-key="about)
```

Comment: Can't you use an html parser to have good selectors? Regex are probably a bad tool for this job

Comment: I recommend using https://regex101.com to create regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the href, you can use `[^"]+` inside of href, this way you regex will not capture more than what you need as it will be stopped by `"`.

You can then create something like `href="([^"]*?)" data-tab-key="about"`.

I'd suggest avoiding using regex to match html though.

Comment: Thanks. But how can i match only the url without the href="

Comment: Here you are only capturing the url, isn't that enough? Otherwise, it should be easy to fix with a positive lookbehind

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
(?i)a class=".+" href="\K.*?(?=" data-tab-key="about)
```

I believe you are struggling to get a variable length look behind to work, which is

```
(?<=a class=".+" href=")
```

`.+` in the above is not a valid syntax as it introduces variable length in a look behind. This is not supported in any of the regex engines I know(I would be happy to know if I'm wrong here).

That said in-order to emulate a variable length look-behind one could use the `\K` flag which resets the starting point of the match to the current position(there by dropping all the the previously grabbed items out of the final match).

Demo regex is [here](https://regex101.com/r/QfONek/1).

Comment: Thanks for the help but for some reason the regex code didnt work on the regex tool i am using..

Comment: @kreatusJohn what tool are you using for this?